# How to reverse 'for loop' for array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have my loop as this in my `.ejs` file, grades is an array of objects coming from express route

```
<% for(const grade of grades){ %>
  <%= grade.year %>
<% } %>
```

Is there any way I could reverse this array, I need the array to be started from the end.
Can anyone help me here...

Comment: `grades.reverse()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% for(const grade of grades.reverse()){ %>
    <%= grade.year %>
<% } %>
```